# Laravel Eloquent Query group by user and order by Max(date)

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have the following table. I am actually designing a simple chat, so, we have the user_id (the person who sends the message) and user_id_to (the person who receives the message).

| id | user_id | user_id_to | message | send_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | test 1 | 01-2-2023 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | test 2 | 02-2-2023 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | test 3 | 03-2-2023 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | test 4 | 05-3-2023 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | test 5 | 08-3-2023 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 | test 6 | 10-3-2023 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | test 7 | 11-3-2023 |
| 8 | 5 | 1 | test 8 | 13-3-2023 |
| 9 | 5 | 1 | test 9 | 15-3-2023 |
| 10 | 5 | 1 | test 10 | 20-3-2023 |
| 11 | 1 | 3 | test 11 | 22-3-2023 |

I want to be able to select the distinct user (grouped by user), and message, order by max send_date.

So, with the above data, the following should be the result.

| id | user_id | user_id_to | message | send_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | 3 | test 11 | 22-3-2023 |
| 10 | 5 | 1 | test 10 | 20-3-2023 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | test 7 | 11-3-2023 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 | test 6 | 10-3-2023 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | test 5 | 08-3-2023 |

I need to use Laravel Eloquent, because with that I can use with('user', 'user_to') to select the users data together.

Answer provided by Karl Hill works, but it didn't select the message column. How can I also select the message column?

Please help.

Comment: Need more data like your model name, relations, what you have tried so far ...

Comment: @salman-a You are correct, I missed that. I have added user #3, and I have also amended the order of the records in the expected result.

Comment: Consider storing the id of the last message in the user table. Once you do that, it becomes easy to write a simple and efficient query (it will execute quickly even if you have millions of messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the latest chat for each distinct pair of users.
I am also assuming that all chat between (1, 2) and (2, 1) is considered one conversation.

To get the top-1-per-group you can use a `not exists` query with a twist:

```sql
select *
from chat as newer
where (
    newer.user_id = ? or
    newer.user_id_to = ?
) and not exists (
    select 1
    from chat as older
    where (
        -- the (user_id, user_id_to) pair needs to match the corresponding
        -- pair from outer query in same order or reversed
        older.user_id = newer.user_id and older.user_id_to = newer.user_id_to or
        older.user_id = newer.user_id_to and older.user_id_to = newer.user_id
    )
    and older.send_date > newer.send_date
)
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2M-cuMIO)
The fiddle also contains a `row_number` solution if your RDBMS supports it.

The eloquent code to produce the above query would be:

```php
$some_user_id = 1;
$query = DB::table('chat as newer')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($some_user_id) {
                $query->where('newer.user_id', '=', $some_user_id)
                    ->orWhere('newer.user_id_to', '=', $some_user_id);
            })
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('chat as older')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->whereColumn('older.user_id', '=', 'newer.user_id')
                        ->whereColumn('older.user_id_to', '=', 'newer.user_id_to')
                        ->orWhereColumn('older.user_id', '=', 'newer.user_id_to')
                        ->whereColumn('older.user_id_to', '=', 'newer.user_id');
                })
                ->whereColumn('older.send_date', '>', 'newer.send_date');
            });
```

Comment: I have tried the not exists query, but it doesn't work with "->with('user', 'user_to')". How can I make it work with "->with('user', 'user_to')"?

Comment: I have figured it out. Now, it works with "with". I use the following:

$latest_chats = Chat::from('chats as newer')
    ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {... ...

But, how can filter it by $user which is the currently logged in user? I add in

                        ->where(['user_id_to' => $user->id])
                        ->orWhere(['user_id' => $user->id])

to the inner query, and it complaints $user is not defined, which is definitely not true. If I add this to the outer query, it will return all records, which is incorrect.

Comment: I already have this above the codes: $user = Auth::user();

Comment: Note that the OP wants a result per user_id, not per (user_id, user_id_to).

Comment: @Olivier based on the second comment from top op wants to find rows where a specific user is either the sender or recipient. Its trivial btw, the OR condition needs to be put in brackets.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgipM.jpg

Please check my screenshot, $some_user_id is defined. But it becomes undefined when we add it to the inner query, where as in the outer query it is fine (just added it there to illustrate). How can we fix this?

Comment: @jk it is a basic PHP concept. Variables defined outside a function are not available inside it (I forgot that too, my bad). See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your Modal name is Message

```
$latestMessages = Message::select('user_id', \DB::raw('MAX(send_date) as latest_date'))
                          ->groupBy('user_id');

$messages = Message::joinSub($latestMessages, 'latest_messages', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('messages.user_id', '=', 'latest_messages.user_id')
                                 ->on('messages.send_date', '=', 'latest_messages.latest_date');
                        })
                        ->with('user', 'user_to')
                        ->orderBy('send_date', 'desc')
                        ->get(['messages.*']);
```

Echo the $messages variable to see the results. This also satisfy your requirement of using:

```
  with('user', 'user_to');
```

to select the user data together with the messages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Eloquent's `groupBy`, `orderBy`, and `with` methods. Convert the `send_date` to a date format that MySQL can understand. You can do this by adding `send_date` to your model's `$dates` property.

```php
protected $dates = ['send_date'];
```

Then, use the `DB::raw` function to select the maximum `send_date` for each `user_id`. You can then group by `user_id` and order by the maximum `send_date`.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$chats = Chat::select(DB::raw('max(id) as id, user_id, user_id_to, max(send_date) as send_date'))
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderBy('send_date', 'desc')
    ->with('user', 'user_to')
    ->get();
```

This query will return the latest chat for each user, not the latest chat for each pair of users. If you want to get the latest chat for each pair of users, you should group by both `user_id` and `user_id_to`.

Comment: I will try to use this and see.. I am very new to Laravel and Eloquent, and will experiment with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: This works well, but turns out I need the latest chat for each pair of users, so I need to group by both user_id and user_id_to. Also, the table has a field called "message". How can I add this field to the query? Meaning, I need the latest chat for each pair of users, including the actual message.

Comment: Could you please help me, how can I add the column "message" to the selected column list?

Answer (score -1):

First, let's see this with a raw SQL query:

```
select latest.id, latest.user_id, latest.user_id_to, latest.message, latest.send_date
from yourtable latest
left join yourtable followup
on latest.user_id = followup.user_id and latest.user_id_to = followup.user_id_to and latest.send_date < followup.send_date
where followup.id is null
```

Here, we find the latest record by left joining `latest` to `followup` based on `user_id` and `user_id_to` matching as well as `followup` being later than `latest`. In the `where` clause we ensure that only those `latest` records are selected that have no `followup` matches, that is, they are indeed the latest.

Now, let's convert this into an Eloquent query:

```
YourTable::DB::table('yourtable as latest')
    ->select(DB::raw("select latest.id, latest.user_id, latest.user_id_to, latest.message, latest.send_date"))
    ->leftJoin('yourtable as followup', function($join) {
          $join->on('latest.user_id', '=', 'followup.user_id');
          $join->on('latest.user_id_to', '=', 'followup.user_id');
          $join->on('latest.send_date', '<', 'followup.send_date');
      })
     ->where(DB::raw('followup.id is null'));
```

Comment: How will that query return the latest record, as there is no group by and no order by?

Comment: Also, I cannot use query builder, because I need to use "with" to return the details for user and user_to.

Comment: @JK it is doing that by left joining `latest` and `followup`, where we exclude all `latest` records using the `where` clause.

Comment: @JK you can use `with` and query builder together. See: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-use-with-in-laravel-db-query-builder

Comment: @JK Test the initial query I have given against your database and see how it works. It has no `group by` either, because we find the latest record by the sheer fact that we search for records which have no followup, notice the where clause.

Comment: I tried:

$latest_chats = DB::table('yourtable as latest')
    ->select(DB::raw("select latest.id, latest.user_id, latest.user_id_to, latest.message, latest.send_date"))
    ->leftJoin('yourtable as followup', function($join) {
          $join->on('latest.user_id', '=', 'followup.user_id');
          $join->on('latest.user_id_to', '=', 'followup.user_id');
          $join->on('latest.send_date', '<', 'followup.send_date');
      })
    ->with('user', 'user_to')
    ->where(DB::raw('followup.id is null'));

Comment: But, I get error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()